# Android - Custom Style for the ListView items in an Activity

Tags: java, android, listview

i want to differentiate the list items by changing the Text style to bold for **"ParentID is null"** and  **"ParentID is not null"** with normal Style. **Please help me with the code to get the customizable listview items.** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here You have to cretae one custom adapter in which you have to define on row layout for list items and you can set different styles for each item 
here is good link for that
[How to create a custom ListView with "extends Activity"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632666/how-to-create-a-custom-listview-with-extends-activity)

Comment: first declare listview in your main layout file then create one custom layout file that declares a layout of single listitems.then create one custom adapter as in example use that custom layout file in that adapter and call that adapter from yout acticity